# Is there a way to remove certain inputs from a window in PySimpleGUI without removing others?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, pysimplegui

I am *new* new to Python/PySimpleGUI, so sorry if this would be incredibly obvious. (Also, yes, this is code I am using from [a Youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/svcv8uub0D0), I am not trying to take any credit for the code below.)

I have a simple program using pandas, pysimplegui, and openpyxl to input a set of values from the end user (using PySimpleGUI windows) into an Excel sheet; however, there are certain fields that I want to keep constant (such as "date" being today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")). Here's how I have tried doing it:

Defining what I want constant as variables:

```
bkey = 'My Name'
today = date.today()
date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
```

And then, in pysimplegui, letting the sg.inputtext() be the variables, e.g.:

```
[sg.Text('Entry By', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(bkey)]
```

For reference, here is a window with *key* as the input:

```
[sg.Text('To Department', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='To Department')]
```

And then in the event of user clicking "Submit" or "Clear," calling def Clear_Input():

```
def clear_input():
for key in values:
    window[key]('')
return None
```

I have no idea why clear_input() is clearing ALL values in the window, because to me it is saying any values as key in the window == '', so anything NOT defined as key (such as bkey) shouldn't be cleared.

Let me know if there is any more info I can give, I'd be glad to give it. Again, newb, sorry in advance.

Here is the full source code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

#color add to window_height
sg.theme('Topanga')

EXCEL_FILE = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\DataEntry.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)
bkey = 'My Name'
today = date.today()
date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please fill out the following fields:')],
    [sg.Text('Service Tag', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Tag')],
    [sg.Text('Serial Number (EPB)', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Serial Number')],
    [sg.Text('Type of Equipment', size=(15,1)), sg.Combo(['Desktop', 'Laptop', 'Monitor', 'Tablet'], key='Type of Equipment')],
    [sg.Text('New/Move', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='New/Move')],
    [sg.Text('User\'s Name', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='User\'s Name')],
    [sg.Text('From Room', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='From Room')],
    [sg.Text('To Room', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='To Room')],
    [sg.Text('To Department', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='To Department')],
    [sg.Text('Date', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(date)],
    [sg.Text('Attached Tag', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Attached Tag')],
    [sg.Text('Entry By', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(bkey)],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Button('Clear'), sg.Exit()]
]



window = sg.Window('simple data entry form', layout)

def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        window[key]('')
    return None


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Clear':
        clear_input()
    if event == 'Submit':
        df = df.append(values, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)
        sg.popup('Data saved!')
        clear_input()

window.close()
```

Comment: You have given us almost nothing here.  Why not show your whole program?  We don't know what `window` is, or what `values` is.  Note that `key` and `bkey` are just names,  There isn't anything in your window called `bkey`.  It might have the string `"My Name"`, and if `"My Name"` is present in `values`, then it's going to get cleared.

Comment: @TimRoberts You're right - apologies for that. Full source code is pasted in original post.

Comment: There will be a default key generated for Input element or some other element if you don't specify the value for both of option `key` and option `k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PySimpleGui.Window.read()` returns two things: `event` and `values`.  `event` contains a description of whatever event triggered the message.  `values` contains a dictionary of all of the input components in your layout.  The key in that dictionary is the `key` parameter from your `Input` item.  The `value` is the current value of that input item.

So, `clear_input` is just running through the set of `Input` elements in your layout, and setting their values to blank.

The key item is that names, like `bkey` and `key` have no meaning at runtime.  They just hold references to objects.  The `Input` objects all have key values, but they are the strings you set up in your layout.

Comment: Ok, got what you've said here. The thing is, I want bkey and date to *not* be cleared during my def clear_input() - how would I do that? I've tried re-defining them in the Submit class (e.g. bkey = 'My name') and it still does not re-populate it.

Comment: If there's a key you don't want cleared, then you need to check for it in the loop that does the clearing.  Thus, `if key != 'My Name':` / `window[key]('')`.

Comment: Ok, I thought I had it, but I do not. Here's what I tried:

`def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        if key != 'Date' or key != 'Entry By':
            window[key]('')
        else:
            break`

And it did not work, every key still clears. In layout, those keys are equal to Entry By and Date, respectively.

Comment: Right.  Think about what you wrote.  EVERY word is either "not equal to Date" or "not equal to Entry By".  You need `and` here, not `or`.  And do not say `else:` / `break`.  Just have the `if` by itself.  If it is one of those two phrases, you want to do nothing.

Comment: Oh, my god. That worked. AND not OR. Geez. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There will be a default key generated for Input element or some other element if you don't specify the value for both of option key and option k.

Some statements updated here for you code

```py
today = date.today()
now = today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")                                                # date is the libray name


    # In layout
    [sg.Text('Date', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(now, key='Date')],             # Define the key
    [sg.Text('Attached Tag', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Attached Tag')],
    [sg.Text('Entry By', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(bkey, key='Entry By')],     # Define the key

# Tuple for the input elements not to clear
not_to_clear = ('Entry By', 'Date')

def clear_input():
    # For elements in the window
    for key, element in window.key_dict.items():
        # If element is Input element and not in the not-to-clear tuple
        if isinstance(element, sg.Input) and key not in not_to_clear:
            element.update('')
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your suggestion. I have implemented your suggestions and I am getting this:


`File "c:\Python\DataEntryExcelForm.py", line 35, in clear_input
    for key, element in window.key_dict():
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

As for the logic of your comment, I get all of it. You are clearing the key value of 'Entry By' & 'Date,' but keeping the date/bkey alive by defining it first.

Comment: Should be `for key, element in window.key_dict.items():`, updated as above.

Comment: Just tested it, that worked. Thank you!